# Difference between /dev/udp and netcat

Tags: networking, syslog, udp, rsyslog, netcat

I have a syslog server listening on `localhost:514` as UDP and would like to write messages to it on that port.  (Using Ubuntu 14.04)

If I run either of these commands from bash it prints the date every 2 seconds to syslog

```
# Using netcat
while true; do sleep 2; date; done | nc -u localhost 514

# Using /dev/udp
while true; do sleep 2; date; done > /dev/udp/localhost/514
```

Now just to test things I kill the syslog server then start it up a few seconds later.

While the syslog process is dead, the `/dev/udp` command every 2 seconds prints an error message to the console, so it recognizes that there is no `localhost:514` for it to write to.

```
date: write error: Connection refused
```

Once syslog is back, these connection refused messages stop and it resumes writing the date to syslog. This is as expected.

But the netcat command doesn't do this. While the syslog process is dead, it doesn't print any output to the console. And when syslog is back, it doesn't continue writing the date to syslog.

Why won't netcat continue writing to localhost:514 when syslog is restarted? How can I get netcat to behave the way `/dev/udp` does in this example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `nc`. The `nc` command uses the `poll` system call to wait until input is received from either `stdin` or the socket.

When a UDP packet has been send to a closed UDP port on the receiving end, an error message is send back. The `poll` call will return this status to the `nc` command, but `nc` does not actually process the error. Instead `nc` goes back to call the `poll` system call again, which returns immediately due to the error still being queued on the socket.

This could have been an infinite loop, where `nc` would consume all the CPU time it could get doing nothing useful.

However it lasts only until the next message is received on `stdin`. At this point `poll` returns both statuses to `nc`, which process the data from `stdin`. Now `nc` will try to write the data from `stdin` to the socket. The attempt to write to the socket will deliver the queued error to `nc`. The write error message will cause `nc` to terminate.

This leaves you with a broken pipe (i.e. a pipe with a writer but no reader). Any attempt to write to the pipe will trigger a `SIGPIPE` signal and if the process isn't killed by the `SIGPIPE` an error from the write call.

`date` isn't handling `SIGPIPE`, so `date` is killed. So the loop keeps going, but each time `date` is killed when attempting to write to the pipe where the reader is long gone.

**What can be done**

Though `nc` looping on the `poll` system call without handing the error is definitely a bug, fixing that bug would not necessarily be enough to cover your need. Simply terminating once the error is returned from `poll` might be considered the correct bugfix for `nc`. One could imagine an additional feature, where `nc` could be told to keep going after an error if given a specific flag.

But you could work around the problem by simply restarting nc in a loop like this:

```
while sleep 1 ; do date ; done | while true ; do nc -u localhost 514 ; done
```

The bug causing periodic excessive CPU usage in `nc`, would still be there. Additionally the combination of that bug and the workaround can cause the first message after the receiving port has been reopened to get lost.

Comment: I'd like to try `socat` instead of `netcat` to see if the bug exists, but the documentation for socat is a bit overwhelming and I've never used it before (can't find simple examples of its usage either). Do you know how I could test this with socat? Like `while true; do sleep 2; date; done | socat .......`.

Comment: @user779159 I have practically no experience with `socat`.